# Split a repository based on commits instead of directory or file type

Tags: git, split, repository, bitbucket, git-filter-branch

My git repository is getting to large, so I want to split it into one or more repositories.
When searching for it I can find many solutions based on `git-filter-branch`, that will rewrite the whole repository.

But the files I want to remove are all isolated to individual commits, so I do not have to rewrite the commits containing the files, I just have to remove those commits. I.e. the commit tags could remain the same. To me it looks like a more beautiful solution than using git-filter-branch.

So my thought are that I should make a copy of the repository, so that when the split is done the users will use the copy instead.
After this I will remove the unwanted commits with something like `git rebase -i` and drops all unwanted commits.
But there are many commits that should be removed, so is there some way that I can run this as a script? Or maybe `git-filter-branch` is doing this already if it is a complete commit that is removed!?

Is there a way to do it on all branches automatically?

So do you think that this is a good approach, or should I use `git-filter-branch` instead?

So what I want to do from this three:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F
  \
   G - H - I - J
```

is to remove C, E and H:

```
A - B  - D  - F
  \
   G - I - J
```

Comment: Another approach is to replace part of the history, see https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with using `rebase` for this.  It only wants to work on at most one branch at a time (and doesn't really address other refs).  It can't handle merges well.  (Evel the relatively newly-added featues that make people like to claim they "finally" added merge support, still don't handle merges well.)

So it really doesn't matter *what* you're trying to do - the point is that you want to change the history of an entire repo, and taht's better suited to `git filter-repo` (or, as you note, `git filter-branch`; but that's an older tool that's fallen out of favor).

Either of those tools can do what you want.  That is, there are options you can set so that, if a commit is rewritten to not make any changes, then that commit is removed.  (So in your example, if you're removing a file, and a commit only modifies that file, then the commit will no longer make any changes and will be removed.)

The usage `filter-branch` and `fitler-repo` are very different, so you'll have to decide which to use first.  Unless you have to use an older version of git that can't support it, `filter-repo` is probably the better recommendation (especially since, based on what you've written, it seems you'd have to learn a new tool either way).

Both tools are also very general-purpose, with lots of options to control what they do; and they're also very poewrful, so that you really should have a decent understanding of them rather than just following some recipe we could give you (and then having no idea what to do if something goes wrong).  So the best advice is to read the docs:

https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html